# Mah Apps Tile Animation

Tags: c#, wpf, mahapps.metro

I would like to add the Live Tile effect to the tiles on my wpf app layout. I'm using the MahApps.Metro library for the visuals. Here is an example of one of the tiles that I have on the layout -

```
<Controls:Tile Height="110" Background="#9c6b50" Width="180" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,105,33,0">
    <Controls:Tile.Content>
        <TextBlock Text="Setup Your Savings Account" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="121" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    </Controls:Tile.Content>
</Controls:Tile>
```

I'd like the end product of the tile to switch between these two texts:

1. Setup your Savings account
2. Click here to Setup your savings account

Answer (score 1):

The generally accepted way to do this is by binding the Text property. A binding would look like this:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=TileText}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="121" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
```

What this does is bind the value of the TextBlock to a property called TileText on the DataContext of the control. You will need to look into DataContext and binding in WPF to understand this.

Once you have a class with the property:

```
public string TileText
{
    get {...}
    set {...}
}
```

And the class is set as the DataContext of the Tile control you can change the value of the TileText property and it will change the text of the TextBlock. This is a simple example of MVVM design and can be a good first step in understanding smart WPF design practices.

Cheers,
Eric

Comment: Thanks sir...which book(s) would you recommend that i read to get myself more comfortable with "smart WPF design practices". Or any good online tutorial/ article you know

Comment: [Try this one](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18270/A-Guided-Tour-of-WPF-Part-3-Data-binding). It is an explanation of Bindings. Bindings are the building blocks of the MVVM pattern. I suggest getting comfortable with the concept of bindings before stepping back to understand the MVVM pattern that is so great with WPF.

Comment: If I might add, [Microsoft Virtual Academy](http://www.microsoftvirtualacademy.com) has plenty of content about XAML and WPF. Some of them are really helpful, and can help OP on some knowledge about the platform. You could also use the examples provided by MahApps. Lot of good ones!

Answer (score 0):

Try this!

```
<controls:Tile Height="110" Background="#9c6b50" Width="180" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,105,33,0">
        <controls:Tile.Style>
            <Style TargetType="controls:Tile">
                <Setter Property="Content">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <TextBlock Text="Setup Your Savings Account" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="121" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Content">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <TextBlock Text="Click here to Setup Your Savings Account" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="121" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </controls:Tile.Style>
    </controls:Tile>
```